# determine previous business date from list of business days

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba

i need to write a sql query that determines the previous business day based on a list of business days.

i need to compare to this list of business days because it takes unique business holidays into consideration (otherwise i would just use the VBASQL WORKDAY function).

desired output is in the 3rd sample table; the tables i need to derive this from are the first 2.

how would i do this?

for example

```
table1.StartingDate
----------
20131105
20131104

BusinessDayTable.Date
----------
20131105
20131104
20131101

OutputTable.StartingDate | OutputTable.PrevBusDate
-------------------------|------------------------
20131105                 | 20131104
20131104                 | 20131101
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different approaches:

With Join:

```
 Select t.StartingDate, Max(b.Date) EndDate
 from table1 t
     left Join BusinessDayTable b
         On b.Date < t.StartingDate
 Group By t.StartingDate -- group by is necessary because 
                         -- `StartingDate` is in select clause.
```

with SubQuery in Join condition:

```
 Select startingDate, b.Date EndDate
 from table1 t
     left Join BusinessDayTable b
         On b.Date = (Select Max(b.Date)
                      From BusinessDayTable 
                      Where Date < t.StartingDate)
```

or with SubQuery in Select:

```
 Select startingDate, 
   (Select Max(Date) 
    from BusinessDayTable 
    Where Date < t.StartingDate) EndDate
 from table1 t
```

Comment: you forgot the 'group by' :)

Comment: ahhh yes, you're right, I was trying to avoid subquery.  In subquery, you don't need group By with Max.  Edited it as I had originally (to use subquery) to illustrate.